# how do we increase font size when using xlop and anyfontsize

Tags: fontsize, xlop

I can get upto 20 pts with this code

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}  
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opadd[voperation=center,carryadd=false] {1}{1}
\end{document}​
```

[image: @20 PT documentclass]

I am trying to use anyfontsize to increase the size like this:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{40}{50}
\opadd[voperation=center,carryadd=false] {1}{1}
\end{document}​
```

I end up getting this (increases the size of the operator and not the operands)

[image]

I really want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need `\selectfont` after any low level change to the font parameters, but by default matching math sizes are not set up for over large sizes, it is simpler to use normal sizes and scale.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
{\fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont
\opadd[voperation=center,carryadd=false] {1}{1}
}

\bigskip


\scalebox{5}{%
\opadd[voperation=center,carryadd=false] {1}{1}%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you change some dimensions based on font (ex, em, \baselineskip), two xlop parameters become wrong: columnwidth and lineheight. They are dimensions and the initial values are 2ex and \baselineskip (resp.)... with the current values of ex and \baselineskip.
So, you have to redefine these parameters, even for values 2ex and \baselineskip:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
{\Huge\opadd{123}{456}}
\qquad
{\Huge\opadd[lineheight=\baselineskip,columnwidth=2ex]{123}{456}}
\par\bigskip
{%
  \fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont
  \opadd[lineheight=\baselineskip,columnwidth=2ex]{123}{456}
}
\qquad
{%
  \fontsize{40}{65}\selectfont
  \opadd[lineheight=\baselineskip,columnwidth=2ex]{123}{456}
}
\end{document}
```